# Android Studio не может установить приложение

Tags: android, android-studio

Проблема заключается в том, что Android Studio видит теоефрон, даже начинает установку, но в процессе установки возникает ошибка, Android Studio думает что приложение уже инсталировано в телефоне, и спрашивает можна ли его удалить, после подтверждения происходит ошибка.

Скриншот ошибки, лог из `Run` добавляю, скриншоты настройки телефона добавляю:

```html
01/11 16:28:35: Launching GRAPH
$ adb push D:\Work\GlabEasyGSM\GRAPH\build\outputs\apk\GRAPH-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/ua.com.glab.easygsmv40
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/ua.com.glab.easygsmv40"
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/ua.com.glab.easygsmv40
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED]


$ adb shell pm uninstall ua.com.glab.easygsmv40
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В настройках телефона стоит разрешение на установку приложений из недоверенных источников?

Comment: @Barmaley, да, стоит.

Comment: Та же проблема, meizu m5. Прошивка с рутом

Answer (score 3):

на xiaomi 4x помогло, рут прова имеелись но глюк всёравно наблюдался.

Go to Settings > Additional settings > Developer options
Disable the "Turn on MUI optimization"
Reboot your phone

Comment: Это помогло на Redmi Note 4, без каких-либо рут прав. Пока не отключил MIUI optimization, включение настроек "Отладка по USB" и "Установка через USB" не давало никаких результатов

Answer (score 2):

Решение проблемы на китайских смартфонах - установка Root прав.

Answer (score 1):

Удалите приложение (и apk) с телефона, и попробуйте установить его ещё раз.

Или другой вариант - просто нажмите "ОК" в этом диалоговом окне:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я предоставил логи того что происходит после нажатия ОК. Решение найдено - надо установить Root права

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернатива установке рут прав (мне помогло).
В Android Studio зайти в Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment> Instant Run и отключить.

Answer (score 1):

Настройки -> Расширенные настройки -> Для разработчиков -> Установка через USB
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло, включение флажка "установка через USB". Но была проблема в том что эта функция просто так не включалась. Для того что бы её включить я вначале выключил оптимизацию MIUI (внизу списка), потом обратно включил её. поставил Конфигурацию USB (в этом же меню) MTP, но и после этого она не включалась. После чего я не теряя надежды включил флажок установку через USB (при нажатии система делала усердный вид, что что-то делает, но после ничего не происходило и он оставался выключенный, повторял несколько раз), и в тот момент когда система думала я запустил установку приложения с android studio, и к моему удивлению всё начало работать. После когда я зашёл в меню настроек разработчика флажок оказался включенным. Выключать боюсь. Поэтому написал такой объёмный ответ) Может кому поможет. Xiaomi Redmi note 4x, MIUI global 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло только то что я пересоздал проект, не оставляя ни одного названия "по умолчанию", перенеся в него все классы и ресуры.